# How to send parameters to EC2 instance aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-step-functions

I am fairly new to AWS and would like your suggestions. The problem I would like to solve is that I want to automate the process. I have this ec2 image running ubuntu and I want to call this executable "executable_hello_world_repeat" inside the image which prints "Hello World" every second. and when calling the executable I want to add input parameters such as "executable_hello_world_repeat -n10" this would print "hello world" 10 times.

Manually I can do the following:

1. go to AWS management console and choose the ec2 image to start
2. check if the instance is running successfully
3. from the terminal call "executable_hello_world_repeat -n10"
4. it prints the "Hello World"

I want to write a program to do them all programatically. Eventually I will have a web page in React/JS and automate this process.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Are you simply wanting to start a script when the EC2 instance boots-up, or are you wanting to activate it _after_ the instance has already been running?

Comment: Both. Script X starts EC2 instance and Script X calls the executable in EC2 instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an Amazon EC2 instance is **first launched**, a [User Data script](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) can be provided, which is automatically executed as the `root` user towards the end of the boot process. You can use this script to install software, configure settings, start process, etc.

Please note that this script only runs on the **first boot**, because the software does not need to be installed on subsequent boots.

If you want a script to run on **every boot**, put it in the `/var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-boot/` directory.

If you *later* want to trigger a script to run, then you will need some mechanism that receives this request and runs the script. A few ways you could do this are:

- Run a web server on the instance and the request comes via an HTTP / REST request, *or*
- Trigger the [AWS Systems Manager Run Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html) that will cause a script to be run on the instance, or even multiple instances, *or*
- Have a program or script running on the instance that is continuously polling an Amazon SQS queue. When a message is received from the queue, trigger a program/script to process the message. This is known as a "Worker" that pulls from the Queue

The EC2 instance is basically just a normal Linux instance, so you'll need to somehow get something to trigger on the instance when desired.